# how to print a series string in a list format?

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code:

```
Height =[9.6, 7.5, 2.2, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.5, 2.3, 7.5, 6.5, 2.7]
for YY in Height: 
    def tall_or_short (YY):
        if YY>5:
            print "tall"
        elif YY>=2:
            print "meduim"
        else:
            print "short"
    str(tall_or_short (YY)) 
HEIGHT = [str(tall_or_short (YY)) for YY in Height]

print str(HEIGHT)
```

Result:

```
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
```

How to fix the problem and show `['tall', 'short', ....., 'medium']`?

Comment: Can you describe your question in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Move your function definition out of your loop.
Call your function from inside your loop.

```
def tall_or_short (YY):
    if YY > 5:
        return "tall"
    elif YY >= 2:
        return "medium"
    else:
        return "short"

height = [9.6, 7.5, 2.2, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.5, 2.3, 7.5, 6.5, 2.7]
transformed = []
for YY in height:
    transformed.append(tall_or_short(YY))
print transformed
```

Results:

```
(tallshort)macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ python tallshort.py 
['tall', 'tall', 'medium', 'short', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'tall', 'tall', 'medium']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for (using python3.4):

```
heights =[9.6, 7.5, 2.2, 1.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.5, 2.3, 7.5, 6.5, 2.7]

heights_str =[]

for height in heights:
    if height > 5:
        heights_str.append("tall")
    elif height >= 2:
        heights_str.append("medium")
    else:
        heights_str.append("short")

print(heights_str)
```

The output:

```
['tall', 'tall', 'medium', 'short', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'medium', 'tall', 'tall', 'medium']
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked!! now i know how to change a number list to a string list :)